# How to delete creating automatic back up file for MS Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, backup, microsoft-excel-2007

Every time I use a file Excel it generate an automatic back up file.

How can I disable this feature?

I use MS Office 2007 with Windows 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open any excel file and choose the "**save as**" option.

When you are in the save as window, below the "File name" and "Save As Type" options, there is an option that reads "**Tools**" with a small drop down arrow next to it. Click on this drop down arrow and then from the dropdown list, choose "**General Options**".

In the window that pops up next, un-check the box that reads " **Always create Backup**"